# How do I force VBA to do real integer math?

Tags: vba

This code should return 0, but it returns 1.  VBA appears to be doing floating point math, even though all numbers are Long integers.

```
Function demo() As Long
    Dim const1 As Long
    Dim const2 As Long
    Dim result As Long
    const1 = 1796&
    const2 = 1798&
    result = const1 / const2
    demo = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the direction of your slash

```
Function demo() As Long
    Dim const1 As Long
    Dim const2 As Long
    Dim result As Long
    const1 = 1796&
    const2 = 1798&
    result = const1 \ const2
    demo = result
End Function
```

`\` will force integer division